# Wit's end with file to dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Python: 2.7.9
I erased all of my code because I'm going nuts.
Here's the gist (its for Rosalind challenge thingy):

I want to take a file that looks like this (no quotes on carets)

">"Rosalind_0304
actgatcgtcgctgtactcg
actcgactacgtagctacgtacgctgcatagt

">"Rosalind_2480
gctatcggtactgcgctgctacgtg
ccccccgaagaatagatag

">"Rosalind_2452
cgtacgatctagc   
aaattcgcctcgaactcg
etc...

What I can't figure out how to do is basically everything at this point, my mind is so muddled. I'll just show kind of what I was doing, but failing to do.

1st. I want to search the file for '>'
Then assign the rest of that line into the dictionary as a key.
read the next lines up until the next '>' and do some calculations and return
findings into the value for that key.
go through the file and do it for every string.

then compare all values and return the key of whichever one is highest. 
Can anyone help?
It might help if I just take a break. I've been coding all day and i think I smell colors.

```
    def func(dna_str):
        bla
        return gcp #gc count percentage returned to the value in dict
```

Comment: So, you want the dictionary to look something like `{'Rosalind_0304':my_function('actgatcgtcgctgtactcg')}`? And then you want the key corresponding to the highest value?

Comment: Yeah. the values will have a number like 60.2048 which is actually a percentage. I'm gonna try to tackle it again, but reading snippets from the file is whats blocking me for some reason.

Comment: Yes, you will need a function that takes a string like `'gattaca'` as an argument, then does its work, then returns a value like `60.2048`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `my_function` somewhere that returns that percentage value:

```
with open('rosalind.txt', 'r') as ros:
    rosa = {line[1:].split(' ')[0]:my_function(line.split(' ')[1].strip()) for line in ros if line.strip()}
top_key = max(rosa, key=rosa.get)
print(top_key, rosa.get(top_key))
```

For each line in the file, that will first check if there's anything left of the line after stripping trailing whitespace, then discard the blank lines. Next, it adds each non-blank line as an entry to a dictionary, with the key being everything to the left of the space except for the unneeded `>`, and the value being the result of sending everything to the right of the space to your function.

Then it saves the key corresponding to the highest value, then prints that key along with its corresponding value. You're left with a dictionary `rosa` that you can process however you like.

---

Complete code of the module:

```
def my_function(dna):
    return 100 * len(dna.replace('A','').replace('T',''))/len(dna)

with open('rosalind.txt', 'r') as ros:
    with open('rosalind_clean.txt', 'w') as output:
        for line in ros:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                output.write('\n'+line.strip())
            elif line.strip():
                output.write(line.strip())

with open('rosalind_clean.txt', 'r') as ros:
    rosa = {line[1:].split(' ')[0]:my_function(line.split(' ')[1].strip()) for line in ros if line.strip()}
top_key = max(rosa, key=rosa.get)
print(top_key, rosa.get(top_key))
```

Complete content of `rosalind.txt`:

```
>Rosalind_6404 CCTGCGGAAGATCGGCACTAGAATAGCCAGAACCG
TTTCTCTGAGGCTTCCGGCCTTCCCTCCCACTAATAATTCTGAGG
>Rosalind_5959 CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCAATTAAGTCCCTATCCA
GGCGCTCCGCCGAAGGTCTATATCCA
TTTGTCAGCAGACACGC
>Rosalind_0808 CCACCCTCGTGGT

ATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGACTGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT
```

Result when running the module:

```
Rosalind_0808 60.91954022988506
```

This should properly handle an input file that doesn't necessarily have one entry per line.

---

See SO's formatting guide to learn how to make inline or block code tags to get past things like `">"`. If you want it to appear as regular text rather than code, escape the `>` with a backslash:

Type:

```
\>Rosalind
```

Result:

>Rosalind

Comment: Thank you, but I'm gonna go ahead and just quit. This is too much for me. I understand what you have written and it is nice, but now I have to write a function and I can't. Thank you though.

Comment: What does the function have to do?

Comment: Thanks. I'll just scrap it I think.

Comment: I've just edited it with a complete module. Can you compare the module and the input file to what you have?

Comment: Same error. although I looked at the way you have the txt file formatted, which is how i originally posted(wrong). and it works if I change the format of the file instead of ' ' i think i replace with '\n' but the actg letters have multiple lines before the next id. the format on very bottom of page is how it actually looks

Comment: That would certainly do it: the module I wrote assumes that each record is contained in one line. Can you scrub the files manually (with a text editor or something), or does the module need to do it automatically?

Comment: automatically preferred. I'll figure it out. Thanks for getting me this far.

Comment: I've edited it to include code that automatically scrubs the file and creates a tidy one to parse. Please see if that works on your original input file.

Comment: it does not. I copied and pasted. Don't worry about it. Thanks for this much.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense why it works for you and not me.

Comment: Also weird that I had to change the return expression to encapsulate everything into floats before the number came out right.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got that part down now. Thanks so much. BUUUUT. Its throwing an error about it.

```
        rosa = {line[1:].split(' ')[0]:calc(line.split(' ')[1].strip()) for line in ros if line.strip()}
```

IndexError: list index out of range

this is my func btw.

```
def calc(dna_str):

    for x in dna_str:
        if x == 'G':
            gc += 1
            divc += 1
        elif x == 'C':
            gc += 1
            divc += 1
        else:
            divc += 1

    gcp = float(gc/divc)

return gcp
```

Comment: `calc` has to initialize its `gc` and `divc` counters (set them to `0`) before adding to them. If your description of `rosalind.txt` is accurate, this function will need to handle lowercase letters, not uppercase. As for the traceback, are there any lines in the file that are anything other than: 1. a blank line, or 2. something in the form `>Rosalind_1234 agtctagca`?

Comment: Also, this function could be simplified to `return 100 * len(dna_str.replace('A','').replace('T',''))/len(dna_str)`.

Comment: i was lazy. the letters are caps. the file looks like this.
>Rosalind_0292\n
letters\n
>Rosalind_2844\n
letters

Comment: Does the file have any lines that don't match the pattern `>Rosalind_1234 agtctagca` (or a blank line)?

Answer (score 0):

Exact test file. no blank lines before or after.
>Rosalind_6404
CCTGCGGAAGATCGGCACTAGAATAGCCAGAACCGTTTCTCTGAGGCTTCCGGCCTTCCC
TCCCACTAATAATTCTGAGG
>Rosalind_5959
CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCAATTAAGTCCCTATCCAGGCGCTCCGCCGAAGGTCT
ATATCCATTTGTCAGCAGACACGC
>Rosalind_0808
CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGAC
TGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT